# how to upgrade from yosemite gm candidate to final version

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, osx-yosemite-beta

running sudo softwareupdate -l from terminal did not give me anything. And app store ask me to download the 5GB+ installation file of the final version.

I am currently running on gm candidate 3.

Can I install and recover the current system using the installation file or wait and try the upgrade? Will the upgrade procedure work in this case?

Comment: Better suited for [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.imore.com/yosemite-gm-3-or-public-beta-6-and-wondering-how-update-final-release

If you're already running OS X Yosemite gold master release candidate 3 (GM 3) or public beta 6 (PB 6), you won't need to update to the final release version in the Mac App Store (MAS). While there are minor differences in build numbers between the versions, Apple is considering both GM 3 and PB 6 as "final" and not offering the MAS version to anyone with either of them already installed.

Comment: I also understand that if 10.10.1 is released, this will be installed normally over GM3 or PB6 'as if' those are the released 10.10. Actually, it makes more sense that way, and saves us the trouble of downloading a 'final version' which has exactly the same binaries anyway (except perhaps for the build number).